# Advise on developing (by self) in analog circuit design field

Tags: analog, development

I am a fresh graduate specialized in analog design and would like to work for an industry. For sure, there are opportunities, however, most of the industries look only for the (industry) experienced people in this area. Hence, with the probability of getting low, with fewer openings and requirement of experience, are there any strategies to develop ourselves (after graduation/self) so that we at least get a chance of interview?

I have some techniques:

- Doing self projects - however, it is vulnerable to be (not considered) as professional experience.
- Investing time in online courses, which are very costly for the analog design field.
- Trying to apply for a non-matching role for which we need to depend on luck, which is highly random.

Hence the above techniques seem to be weak for the areas of analog circuit design because for a software/IT role, there are plenty of online certifications/projects, which would be respected because the results are instant. However, for analog circuit design, there are not any certifications to at-least get an interview.

Therefore, I need some guidance on how to develop in this field (after graduation) by self study.

Comment: I contest the "most look only for experienced people" assertion. That's the point of entry-level positions, of which I think there are quite a few more in EE than other industries.

Comment: I look for the ability to **complete** a project and to navigate through project unknowns without a lot of hand-holding. Projects completed as a hobbyist is fine, so they do NOT have to be commercial projects. But they do have to be projects demonstrating both non-trivial and completed/working. I'd expect them to be able to find their own solutions to problems others have already solved many times before without my having to walk them step by step through it. They need to know how to research the work of others and apply what they learn without me carrying them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do self projects, I tried to start a business selling hardware. Then I found out that there is little money in that and I hate writing software so I bailed out. In the process I hand built several PCB's. I also did the equivalent of about 5 senior projects, and took every class that had a design project lab. (I didn't sleep for two semesters.) I also joined some student design teams. I did this because I enjoy learning, not because I wanted an awesome job. I also got a masters degree.

Because of this I landed a senior analog designer job, because I had the necessary experience and I had been designing hardware for a few years as a student.

The first thing is work hard and know stuff and do stuff. Get your hands dirty and get some hardware designs and implement them. Not every employer will look past your schooling to look and see what you actually know, but find the right employer.

A graduate that hasn't touched any hardware has many lessons to learn.
School will only teach one how to create designs, but not how to implement them. You must have *working knowledge* and actually going through the design process and making mistakes and learning from them to become valuable to industry.

Comment: read the book "Grey and Meyer" on analog IC design. Then build some differential pair amplifiers. Buy a meter and scope and power supply, or find someone who will let you assist them in using their equipment. Then build a 10 transistor audio power amplifier, to learn diffpairs and current sources and biasing and feedback stability and VDD filtering.

Comment: There is a book by Douglas Self on audio power amplifiers. It may even be available for free download. Read that book, and build circuits. In some cases, you can use daisy-chain grounds. In some cases, you will need GROUND PLANES. A skilled analog designer knows when each is the safe way to have "grounds" be effective.